# Does std::future wait on destruction

Tags: c++, concurrency

**Question**
Does std::future call wait() or get() on destruction?

**Example**

```
void fun()
{
     std::future<int> fut = my_thread_pool.submit(some_work);
}//is fut.wait() or fut.get() called? here
```

Comment: why should it do that? Why should it wait for the result to be available if you do not use that result?

Comment: It will only block if it was created by `std::async`.

Comment: The answer is no, except for when it is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: [The View from the C++ Standard meeting September 2013 Part 2 of 2.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/the_view_from_the_c_standard_meeting_september_2013_part_2?lang=en)

> On the issue that async destructors should not block we devoted a
>   great deal of discussion on it. [..] **The only position that received
>   considerable support was [..] giving advisory that future destructors
>   will not block, unless returned from async, making it the notable
>   exception.** [..] After significant discussion, the only part that we
>   tried to carry was N3776, an attempt to clarify the position that
>   ~future and ~shared_future don’t block except possibly in the presence
>   of async. There was an attempt to issue a deprecation along the lines
>   of C. Deprecate async without replacement. This motion was actually
>   almost put forward. But [..] it died even before it reached the
>   operating table.

Also check: [N3679: Async() future destructors must wait](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3679.html)

> **The basic issue**
>
> Futures returned by async() with async launch policy wait in their
>   destructor for the associated shared state to become ready. This
>   prevents a situation in which the associated thread continues to run,
>   and there is no longer a means to wait for it to complete because the
>   associated future has been destroyed. Without heroic efforts to
>   otherwise wait for completion, such a "run-away" thread can continue
>   to run past the lifetime of the objects on which it depends.
>
> As an example, consider the following pair of functions:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>   vector<int> v;
>   ...
>   do_parallel_foo(v);
>   ...
> }
>
> void do_parallel_foo(vector<int>& v) {
>   auto fut = no_join_async([&] {...  foo(v); return ...; });
>   a: ...
>   fut.get();
>   ...
> }
> ```
>
> If no_join_async() returns a future whose destructor does not wait for
>   async completion, everything may work well until the code at a throws
>   an exception. At that point nothing waits for the async to complete,
>   and it may continue to run past the exit from both do_parallel_foo()
>   and f(), causing the async task to access and overwite memory
>   previously allocated to v way past it's lifetime.
>
> The end result is likely to be a cross-thread "memory smash" similar
>   to that described in N2802 under similar conditions.
>
> This problem is of course avoided if get() or wait() is called on
>   no_join_async()-generated futures before they are destroyed. The
>   difficulty, as in N2802, is that an unexpected exception may cause
>   that code to be bypassed. Thus some sort of scope guard is usually
>   needed to ensure safety. If the programmer forgets to add the scope
>   guard, it appears likely that an attacker could generate e.g. a
>   bad_alloc exception at an opportune point to take advantage of the
>   oversight, and cause a stack to be overwritten. It may be possible to
>   also control the data used to overwrite the stack, and thus gain
>   control over the process. This is a sufficiently subtle error that, in
>   our experience, it is likely to be overlooked in real code.

Comment: If i understand correctly. The answer is it depends.

Comment: @user1235183:- Yes you can say that :)

Comment: Please quote a _standard_. None of this is an authoritative declaration of the actual behaviour.